# Make nested queries with client

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am making a query, and depending on the result I want to make another query. My code looks like this:

```
client.query(Q1, (err, res2) => {
    if (condition(res2)) {
        client.query(Q2), (err, res3) => {
            console.log(res3)
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Condition not fulfilled")
    }
})
```

Both queries take effect, but `res3` is never logged. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Comment: You're doing `client.query(Q2); ((…) => {…});`. You should be doing `client.query(Q2, (…) => {…});`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You closed a brace too early in `client.query(Q2), (err, res3) => {`
This should be:

```
client.query(Q2, (err, res3) => {
```